# Dynamically assigning the timer interval

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a function that needs to be run for every 15 minutes using the timer in VB.net.

But the challenge present here is, if i start the timer, say at 2:00 AM, the actual function will be executed at 2:15 AM after which the same function will be executed for every 15 mins.

I have a sub "Timer" in which the timer is started and the Addhandler operator calls the "ONhandler" function for every 15mins.

```
private mytimer as timer
private sub Timer()
{
with mytimer
.autoreset=true
.enabled=true
.interval=900000
.start
end with
AddHandler mytimer.elapsed ,assressof onhandler
console.readkey()
}

onhandler(byval source as oblject,byval e as elapsedeventargs)
{
Performs the DB operations.
}
```

Initially I had a couple of logic that would start the timer exactly at every 00,15,30,45th mins of each and every hour. Assuming that I start the application at 1:55AM, the logic would ensure that the applications **sleeps** till it reaches 2:00AM and at 2:00 AM, the **timer would start**. After 15 mins, i.e 2:15AM, the function will get executed.

But what I need is , I dont want my application to wait for 15 mins from 2:00 till 2:15. Instead it should process at 2:00 and then start the timer. To overcome this, I had included a new function "onhandler" with same name of AddHandler method which does the same process.

```
private sub Timer()
{
onhandler()     ****New function namesd as AddHandler method
with mytimer
.autoreset=true
.enabled=true
.interval=900000
.start
end with
AddHandler mytimer.elapsed ,assressof onhandler
console.readkey()
}

onHandler()
{
Do same DB function
}
```

After implementing the new logic, 
if I start the application at 1:55 AM, my app would sleep till 2:00 AM after which the Onhandler() method inside sub will get executed first and it would get completed at 2:01Am.
Now the timer is started for 15 mins and the the next set of process is executed at 2:16AM as the timer is set for a 15 min interval. But I need my process to run exactly at 2:15AM. In other words, the timer interval must be for 14mins and not 15 mins.

another example is, I start the application at 3AM and if it ends at 3:03Am, then the time must have an interval of 12 mins and not 15 mins, for the next run.

IS there any way to make the timer interval dynamic for each and every time the process gets completed based on the process ending time???

PS : I am new to DotNet and have been cracking my head on this issue for the past few days. Guys, kindly help me out here.

Thanks in advance,
Madhu.

Comment: What a strange VB.net are you using with all those curly brackets and no End Sub, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to run a [Windows Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task) at specific times. But if you really want to write this in your application, you could wake your program every minute to check the time and just add this to the called method:

```
    Dim d = DateTime.Now
    if(Not (d.Minute = 0 OrElse d.Minute = 15 OrElse d.Minute = 30 OrElse d.Minute = 45)) Then
        Return 'Quits if the current time is not right
    End If
```

Comment: scenario : I have a code snippet that needs to be triggered for every 15th minute exactly.                                                 If snippet takes 14 mins to complete, then the next trigger must occur in 1 min,                                                                         If snippet takes 12 mins to complete, then the next trigger must occur in 3 mins,                                                    and so on . . . . How can i achieve this in DotNet?

Comment: I had to type in the whole code from a place where i can't do a cut-copy-past. hence the problem in formatting it. If your require any more detail in solving my problem, let me know. So that i can furnish you with the required details.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MadhuSharan change your timer to run every 60 seconds and add the code I wrote in the beginning of the called function. It should work

Comment: assuming that I start my application at 2:00 AM, then, on starting my app with a 60 sec interval, it would initially wait for 60 seconds after which it would execute your snippet. And if the 15th minute condition is satisfied, it would continue to execute my snippet. But i don't want it to have a 60 second wait. Cause the whole application is very time sensitive even to 1/10ths of a second. Hope you get the problem. I want the app to start immediately on touching any of the 15th minute and then start again at the next 15 minute SHARP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MadhuSharan Then run a Windows Task. Schedule it to run at those times.

Comment: that's what i initially did. But for a business requirement, i am forced to not use the Windows Task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar once. I would have a variable called NextExecutionTime which would contain the next time the process need to be executed.

At first it would be (example) 2am.

I would then have a timer every minute and if the current time was equal or greather than NextExecutionTime, I would execute the process and setup the NextExecutionTime variable to the next time I wanted the process to run.